# Error on loading google map twice, "Loader must not be called again with different options."

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, google-maps

I am using `@googlemaps/react-wrapper` for my maps, one of them is using the heatmap library, and another one is not, although they are on different pages it still crashes when the user navigates between pages

`Loader must not be called again with different options. {"apiKey":"***","id":"__googleMapsScriptId","libraries":[],"url":"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"} !== {"apiKey":"***","id":"__googleMapsScriptId","libraries":["visualization"],"url":"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"}`

```
import { Wrapper } from "@googlemaps/react-wrapper";
import { FC } from "react";
import { Route, Switch } from "react-router";


export const Map: FC = () => {
  return (
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/page1" exact>
          <Wrapper apiKey={MAP_API_KEY} libraries={["visualization"]}>
            <MapComponent />
          </Wrapper>
        </Route>
        <Route path="/page2" exact>
              <Wrapper apiKey={MAP_API_KEY}>
                <MapComponent />
            </Wrapper>
        </Route>
      </Switch>
  );
};
```

MapComponent:

```
const MapComponent: FC = () => {
  const [map, setMap] = useState<google.maps.Map>();
  const ref = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (ref.current && !map) {
      setMap(
        new window.google.maps.Map(ref.current, {
          center: DEFAULT_MAP_COORDINATES,
        }),
      );
    }

  }, [ref, map]);

  return (
    <div>
      <div ref={ref}  />
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: I find two solutions for that:
1- Use one wrapper for both maps
2-Use the same options for all maps event unused ones

Answer (score 1):

The issue can be solved by giving **the same configuration** for the google map  whenever you initiate more than one instance of it in the same screen.

In your case, it's passing the same props.

```
import { Wrapper } from "@googlemaps/react-wrapper";
import { FC } from "react";
import { Route, Switch } from "react-router";


export const Map: FC = () => {
  return (
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/page1" exact>
          <Wrapper apiKey={MAP_API_KEY} libraries={["visualization"]}>
            <MapComponent />
          </Wrapper>
        </Route>
        <Route path="/page2" exact>
              <Wrapper apiKey={MAP_API_KEY} libraries={["visualization"]}>
                <MapComponent />
            </Wrapper>
        </Route>
      </Switch>
  );
};
```

For some others, who may be using **useJsApiLoader**

Just make sure that the configuration is the same in all the instances:
you can find my case explained in this issue: [How to avoid 'Loader must not be called again with different options' error when using nonce in useJsApiLoader?](https://github.com/JustFly1984/react-google-maps-api/discussions/3023)